# Is it possible to get (force) absolute accuracy on AVDepthData from IPhoneX camera?

Tags: ios

I need to get distance from the camera to points in the camera image with `AVDepthData`. I understand there are two kinds of accuracy associated to `AVDepthData`: relative and absolute, the latter being the one which corresponds to real life distance.

I cannot seem to generate an AVDepthData with absolute accuracy. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVDepthData` is a generic model object for representing depth maps from a variety of possible sources, including parallax-based disparity inference, time-of-flight-based depth inference, data recorded by third-party cameras, or data synthesized by a 3D rendering engine. Thus, it can represent and describe more types of data than the device you're currently using can capture.

(It's like having an image format that supports 10-bit-per-component color: just because `UIImage` or some other API can tell you it's holding a wide-color image doesn't mean you have a camera that captures such images.)

More specifically... you didn't say whether you're using the front or back camera on iPhone X, but that matters quite a bit to what kind of depth maps you can capture.

- `builtInDualCamera`, which iPhone X has for the back-facing camera (as do iPhone 7/8 Plus), infers disparity — which is not quite the same as depth, but related — by analyzing the parallax offsets between two camera images. This technique doesn't produce absolute measurements of depth, but because disparity is inversely proportional to depth you can know which points are deeper than others. (And using the `cameraCalibrationData` you can do some math and maybe get some decent *estimates* of absolute depth.)
- `builtInTrueDepthCamera`, which iPhone X (and so far only iPhone X) has for its front-facing camera, can measure disparity or depth with time-of-flight analysis. (And <strike>sharks with fricking</strike> laser beams!) This technique produces absolute measurements pretty well, as long as you can safely assume the speed of light.

Which technique is used determines what kind of measurement you can get, and which technique is used depends on the capture device you select. (And by the way, there's a wealth of information on how these techniques work in the [WWDC17 talk on capturing depth](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/).)

If you're looking for back-camera depth measurements in an absolute frame of reference, you might do better to look at ARKit — that's not going to get you accurate depth values for every pixel, because it depends on coarse scene reconstruction, but the distance values you can get are absolute.

Comment: Do you know in case of absolute values if those are absolute distance and if they can be used to measure distance from camera to the focused object? I've tried to extract pixel values from the depthData.depthDataMap to do that but without luck, I don't know if my pixel data reading is wrong or if it's something else.